# new Datamap() keeps a shared state of memory between invocations

Tags: javascript, datamaps

It seems that with this code:

```
var map = null;
map = new Datamap({
    // Conf 1 ...
});
// Draw map on DOM
// Remove map from DOM and recreate another map
map = null;
map = new Datamap({
    // Conf 2 ...
});
```

after the second assignment `map` and the resulting Datamap is a mixture of `Conf 1` and `Conf 2`.
How this could happen?

Here is a live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mztyLh66/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to Datamap implementation of [defaults](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/v0.5.1/src/js/datamaps.js#L618).

In the line of code:

```
if (obj[prop] == null) obj[prop] = source[prop];
```

`obj[prop]` is a pointer to `source[prop]`, this cause a shared state of memory between different instances of `new Datamap()`.

I've addressed the problem using a deep copy:

```
// Deep copy if property not set
if (obj[prop] == null) {
    if (typeof source[prop] == 'function') {
        obj[prop] = source[prop].bind({});
    }
    else {
        obj[prop] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source[prop]));
    }
}
```

and opened a [pull request](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/pull/298) to fix it.